# expecting primary expression before token in c++

Tags: c++

Here is the problem:

In console.cpp

```
void Console::PrintMedicine(Medicine* m){
    int ID = Medicine.getID(); //here i get the error expecting primary expression before "." token, it doesn't work with -> either
    cout<<"The Medicine's ID is: ";
    cin>>ID;
}
```

class Medicine:

what's private:

```
private:
    int ID;
    std::string nume;
    double concentratie;
    int cantitate;
```

what's public

```
public:
    Medicine();  //implcit constructor
    Medicine(int ID, std::string nume, double concentratie, int cantitate);//constructor with parameteres
    ~Medicine(); //destructor
```

//the getID function

```
        const int& Medicine::getID() const{
    return this->ID;
}
```

//the getName function

```
const std::string& Medicine::getName() const{
    return this->nume;
}
```

//the getConcentration function

```
const double& Medicine::getConcentration() const{ 
    return this->concentratie;

}
```

//the getQuantity function

```
const int& Medicine::getQuantity() const{
    return this->cantitate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `Medicine.getID()` is incorrect. `Medicine` is the name of a *class*, and you can't use the dot operator to access its members. First, you need an *instance* of `Medicine` whose members you want to access; second, if you have a *pointer* to that instance, you need to use the arrow operator (`operator ->`).

Therefore, it should be:

```
void Console::PrintMedicine(Medicine* m){
    int ID = m->getID();
//           ^^^

// ...
}
```